# How to create an efficient 2D grid in C++?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I want to create a really easy to use 2D Grid. Each cell in the grid needs to be able to store a load of data. Ideally I would like to be able to traverse through the grid one cell at a time, as well as obtain the immediate neighbours of any of the grid cells.

My first thought was to store a vector of pointers to a Cell's neighbours (4 in total), then create convenience functions for leftNeighbour, rightNeighbour, etc. Connecting up the grid after initialization.

The std::vector is supposed to be a dynamically resizeable array, so this strikes me as rather unnecessary if I'm only going to hard-code the positions of the pointers (0 == left, 1 == right, etc). However, it does allow a nicer way of iterating through the neighbours of a cell. The other thing I have to consider is if the cell is on a border with the edge of the grid (whether to test for this or just implicitly extend the grid by one cell so that this will never happen).

Can anyone suggest a better alternative, or does this sound like a reasonable design?

Thanks, Dan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a four-direction iterator, make your own:

```
template<typename T, int width, int height>
class Grid {
    public:
        T data[width * height];

        iterator begin() {
            return iterator(data);
        }

        iterator end() {
            return iterator(data + width * height);
        }

        class iterator {
            public:
                iterator(const iterator &other) :
                    ptr(other.ptr)
                {
                }

                iterator &left() const {
                    return iterator(ptr - 1);
                }

                iterator &right() const {
                    return iterator(ptr + 1);
                }

                iterator &up() const {
                    return iterator(ptr - width);
                }

                iterator &down() const {
                    return iterator(ptr + width);
                }

                iterator &operator++() {
                    ++ptr;
                    return *this;
                }

                iterator &operator--() {
                    --ptr;
                    return *this;
                }

                iterator operator++(int) {
                    ++*this;
                    return iterator(ptr + 1);
                }

                iterator operator--(int) {
                    --*this;
                    return iterator(ptr - 1);
                }

                T operator*() const {
                    return *ptr;
                }

            private:
                iterator();
                iterator(T *ptr_) :
                    ptr(ptr_)
                {
                }

                T *ptr;

                friend class Grid;
        };
};
```

You may want to detect if you hit the edge of your grid, among other things, and that would have to be implemented.

Comment: one thing i don't understand:
why do you return new iterators for left,right,etc and this for ++ and --?

Answer (score 3):

I would go for Boost.MultiArray

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [GIL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/gil/doc/index.html), which is a generic image processing library. Among other things, it has 2D iterators for iterating over images, and being really generic, you might be able to use it directly for your stuff as well. It's surely at least worth a look how  this could be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you don't want the I-would-think-of-this-first method of `std::vector<std::vector<T> >`, but rather something which allows more complicated structures.

In that case, why not make a `Node` class (or struct):

```
template<typename T>
class Node {
    public:
        typedef Node<T> *iterator;
        // and const_iterator

        T data;

        Node(T data_ = T()) :
            data(data_)
        {
        }

        Node<T> *&left() {
            return neighbors[0];
        }

        // etc.

        iterator begin() {
            return neighbors;
        }

        iterator end() {
            return neighbors + 4;
        }

    private:
        Node<T> *neighbors[4];
};
```

This is iterable (which is one of your criteria) and doesn't use dynamic allocation for storing the neighbors.

Comment: Do not use vector<vector<T>>, it has horrible performance due to no cache locality. Use a flat vector<T> instead, and index it with y*w+x (this can be easily encapsulated).

Comment: @Iraimbilanja, I would agree, but resizing the map in the X direction would be very expensive in that case.  If the size was static, a flat array would probably be best.